# How can I recreate this scrollbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to recreate the "try-it" section on this website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior. I have a similar aspect of this I want to use but I'm trying to understand how the scrollbox links in that website does not move the entire webpage.

I tried to recreate something similar to this but when I click the links it moves the entire webpage then goes to the desired section on the scrollbox.

Comment: It might help to show the code you've got so far and demonstrate what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The try it section is rendered in an `<iframe>`. It doesn't move the entire page because the links and targets are in same `<iframes>` viewport. If the content of the `<iframe>` creates a scroll bar then the links do get moved up.

If we modify [the example in Examples section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#setting_smooth_scroll_behavior) and increase content height so that the entire output gets scroll bar then you'll notice it does move the entire output:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav,
.scroll-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  width: 339px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.scroll-container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.scroll-page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.spacer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#page-1">1</a>
  <a href="#page-2">2</a>
  <a href="#page-3">3</a>
</nav>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-1">1</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-2">2</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-3">3</div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to work only on the `scroll-container` then a little bit JavaScript is needed:

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const container = document.querySelector(".scroll-container");

function linkClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = e.target.getAttribute("href");
  const targetElement = document.querySelector(target);
  container.scroll({
    top: targetElement.offsetTop,
    left: 100,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}

for (let link of nav.children) {
  link.addEventListener("click", linkClick);
}
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav,
.scroll-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  width: 339px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.scroll-container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* needed for offsetTop */
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.spacer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#page-1">1</a>
  <a href="#page-2">2</a>
  <a href="#page-3">3</a>
</nav>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-1">1</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-2">2</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-3">3</div>
</div>
```